# phpmyadmin no login page, a lot of gibberish (ubuntu 16), php7.0

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, lamp

I have a problem with PHPMyAdmin login page on localhost. There is no login form, just a lot of gibberish, actually a lot of PHP code i don't understand.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGkv5.png)

Installed LAMP several time with PHPMyAdmin, and always the same. LAMP is working fine, only PHPMyAdmin get this error. I m using Ubuntu 16.04...
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP is not executed, that's why we can see the source code of phpMyAdmin in your screenshot.

Try running this command :

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page) post should help you to activate php in your apache2 configuration

Comment: i have installed php7 and php5 has no installation candidate when i run that command